# Convert JSON array[array[String]] to Java array

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a JavaScript JSON array[array[String]] called `jsonArray` in my `JSP1.jsp`.

I am converting `jsonArray` to a String `jsonArrayStr` using `JSON.stringify(jsonArray)` in `JSP1.jsp`.

I am passing `jsonArrayStr` as a parameter while calling another JSP `JSP2.jsp` this way-

```
"JSP2.do?jsonArrayStr="+jsonArrayStr
```

In `JSP2.jsp`, I am doing this-

```
String jsonArrayStr = request.getParameter("jsonArrayStr");
```

Now how do I convert `jsonArrayStr` to **Java array** (`JSP2.jsp` doesn't contain any JavaScript code)

Summary-

I have a JavaScript JSON Array in a `JSP1.jsp`, which I want to access as a normal Java array/arraylist in `JSP2.jsp`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Are you starting out with a one-dimensional array, or a two-dimensional array? Does your array contain just Strings, or does it contain arrays that contain strings? 

JSON.stringify() on e one-dimensional array would look like:

    ["a", "b", "c", "x", "y", "z"]

JSON.stringify() on a two-dimensional array would look like:

    [["a", "b", "c"],["x"],["y","z"]]

Comment: it looks like  `[["a", "b", "c"],["x"],["y","z"]]`

Comment: @user1649068 you want to create a array of java objects from jsonarray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so you have a two-dimensional array of strings represented as a JSON like this stored in a Java String:

```
[["a", "b", "c"],["x"],["y","z"]]
```

You need to somehow parse or "deserialize" that value into a Java String[][]. You can use a library like from http://www.json.org/java/index.html or http://jackson.codehaus.org/ or you can try to do it manually. Manually could be a little tricky but not impossible. The json.org library is very simple and might be good enough. The code would be something like this (I haven't tried/tested this):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonArrayStr); // JSONArray is from the json.org library
String[][] arrayOfArrays = new String[jsonArray.length()][];
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray innerJsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonArray.get(i);
    String[] stringArray = new String[innerJsonArray.length()];
    for (int j = 0; j < innerJsonArray.length(); j++) {
        stringArray[j] = innerJsonArray.get(j);
    }
    arrayOfArrays[i] = stringArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

somethingk like this

```
ArrayList<String> strings= new ArrayList<String>();     
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)jsonObject; 
if (jsonArray != null) { 
   int len = jsonArray.length();
   for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
    list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
   } 
} 

String[] Stringarray = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);
```

Comment: According to my question, what is JSONObject here? `jsonArray` or `jsonArrayStr`?

Comment: So, u mean to say there is no need for me to `stringify()` the json object? I will be able to directly access the JSONobject across JSP pages without passing them?

Comment: yes, directly pass the jsonArray as request parameter to jsp2 and in jsp2 do as mentioned above :)

Comment: are you talking about `net.sf.json.JSONArray`

Comment: This is how I am passing the array value to another JSP as u said-

`"JSP2.do?jsonArray="+jsonArray;`

Comment: I tried to the way u suggested - `JSONArray javaArray = (JSONArray) jsonArray;` and the compiler is not accepting that. It says - `Cannot cast from String to JSONArray`

Comment: getParameter takes only `String` and getAttribute takes any `Object`. But the challenge is I am using only Javascript in `JSP1.jsp`

Comment: i mean request.setAttribute()

Comment: I understand that. But it's a JavaScript array and not a Java array.